# React component not re-rendering when array prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want my `App` component to display keys every time `keys` changes. I'm doing this by passed keys as a `prop` of `App`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

let keys: string[] = [];

// This is what is supposed to happen in the real app
// document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  // keys.push(event.key)
// });

setTimeout(() => {
  keys.push('a');
}, 1000)

function App({ keys }: { keys: string[] }) {
  let [keysState, setKeysState] = useState(keys)

  useEffect(() => {
     setKeysState(keys)
  }, [keys])

  return (
    <div>
      {keysState.map((key: string) => (
        <li>{key}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App keys={keys} />, rootElement);
```

However, App isn't re-rendering and displaying keys new value:

https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-props-on-react-root-component-forked-3mv0xf?file=/src/index.tsx

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Note: I tried: `setKeysState([...keys, 'a'])`. That doesn't re-render `App` either.

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-props-on-react-root-component-forked-3mv0xf?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Your code sandbox is different from your code snippet in your question

Comment: @Andrew Okay, I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data that is dynamic needs to be managed by React. Put your event inside the component and update local state.

```
function App({ initialKeys }: { initialKeys: string[] }) {
  const [keys, setKeys] = React.useState(initialKeys);
  console.log(keys);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const append = (e) => {
      setKeys([...keys, e.key]);
    };
    document.addEventListener("keypress", append);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keypress", append);
    };
  }, [keys]);

  return (
    <div>
      {keys.map((key: string, idx) => (
        <li key={idx}>{key}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-props-on-react-root-component-forked-l869dd?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: you suppose to change state in a timeout rather than instantly right before component initializing

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to render `keys` in the React component without putting the `keypress` logic inside it? For example, detecting changes in `key` and re-rendering the component?

Answer (score 1):

if you use the below strategy it works as you want it to work.
React cannot see state changes out of its built-in functions so it didn't track the change on your array which was out of its state scope

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let keys: string[] = [];

function App(props: any) {
  const [keys, oldKeysState] = useState(props.keys);
  const [keysState, setKeysState] = useState(keys);

  useEffect(() => {
    setKeysState(keys);
  }, [keys]);

  // componentWillMount
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      oldKeysState([...keys, "a"]);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {keysState.map((key: string) => (
        <li>{key}</li>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setKeysState([...keysState, "+"])}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App keys={keys} />, rootElement);
```